# Bash/Shell Compare a command date/time output with current date/time

Tags: bash, shell

May I know how can I compare the date from a command output with date command. I have no idea how do I compare them. Basically, I want to compare the command output date/time and current date/time to check the interval time between them. For example:

> Command output **date/time = Mar 6 05:37**
>
> Current **date/time = Mar 6 05:38**

Therefore, interval **time = 00:01** which is **1 minute**. Appreciate if anyone could assist me on this.

```
ls -lrt | tail -1

date
```

[Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcJxd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the time in seconds since Epoch.

```
startdate=$(ls -lrt --time-style=+"%s" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $6; }')
enddate=$(date +"%s")
echo "Start date $startdate"
echo "End date $enddate"
difference=$(expr $enddate - $startdate)
echo "Seconds difference $difference"

seconds=$((difference%60))
minutes=$((difference/60%60))
hours=$((difference/60/60%24))
days=$((difference/60/60/24))
printf '%02d:' $days
printf '%02d:' $hours
printf '%02d:' $minutes
printf '%02d\n' $seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work. I get return value as per below: 

date: extra operand `%s'
Try `date --help' for more information.
Start date
End date 1551855342
expr: syntax error
Difference

Comment: Can you try `ls -lrt --time-style=+"%s" | tail -1` and see what you get.

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 userad usersys 679960039 1551855593 FILE_1.log

Comment: Can you try `date +"%s"` and see what you get.

Comment: I get this: 1551856671

Comment: How about `ls -lrt --time-style=+"%s" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $6; }`?

Comment: I get this: 1551855593

Comment: So the problem appears to be with expr?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I accidentally removed a space after the date in my script, instead of date +"%s", I put it date+"%s" so the error rise there. I got the difference of 176, but is it possible to show the difference in hours and minutes? say 00:03 minutes

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "rame" > somefile #some dile
lastModified="$(stat -c %Y somefile)" #last modification date as seconds since Epoch

now=$(date +%s) #now time
d=$(($now-$lastModified)) #difference in seconds 

echo $d
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for replying. But I do not want to export it into a file. I want it to be done within the terminal.